# Groovy check for key in map, is trying to access the map value correct?

Tags: groovy

I'm new to groovy and both of the below seem to be valid, but I wanted to know in what scenario, if any, the first option would return groovy false and give me a key lookup error. Or, is this always OK in groovy? Googling didn't return any detail...

```
mapFoo = ['keyOne': 'valueOne', 'keyTwo': 'valueTwo']
keyExists = false

// what is the downside of using this
if (mapFoo['keyThree']){
    keyExists = true
}

// vs contains()
if (mapFoo.containsKey('keyThree')){
   keyExists = true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The downside of the first one is that the value might be zero, false, the empty string, or indeed `null` (thanks Szymon )

All of these will also be considered false

The second one is more trustworthy in these potential situations, and also better expresses your intent to future readers of your code

However, if the scope of the map is small and you know the possible values, it's much quicker to type

```
boolean keyExists = mapFoo.keyThree
```

Comment: Also, `null` value has to be taken into account. In this case, the key `keyThree` exists, but it stores a `null` value - both methods return a different result.